# Spring + Atomikos batch insert/update

Tags: spring, batch-processing, jta, atomikos

I managed to configure spring + atomikos to have global transactions across multiple databases, e.g., updating or inserting records transactionally. I have been using the @Transactional annotation together with the SqlUpdate or BatchSqlUpdate classes to perform database transactions. Here's a code example:

```
@Transactional
public void insertBatchIntoT1(List<Integer> ids, List<String> names) {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
        int id = ids.get(i);
        String name = names.get(i);
        params.put("id", id);
        params.put("name", name);
        for (BatchSqlUpdate u : insertIntoT1)
            u.updateByNamedParam(params);
    }
    for (BatchSqlUpdate u : insertIntoT1)
        u.flush();
}
```

The method takes a list of ids and names (it could be a list of custom POJO as well) and for each item in the list it sets the parameters in each batch update defined for each DataSource object (using a prepared statement defined at initialization) and performs the update on each. The BatchSqlUpdate is then flushed for each DataSource.
I was wondering if this could be done in a different way: is it possible to incrementally add records to the BatchSqlUpdate without triggering a commit? For example, I'd like to be able to define three methods: startBatchUpdate(), addToBatch(int id,String name) and flushBatch() and have a single transaction between the first and third method call. I tried using the Propagation.REQUIRED attribute but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Any ideas?
I hope I was clear in my question!
Thanks

Comment: Hmmm. Looks like what you want is the XA protocol aka 2 phase commits:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol

http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/WhatIsXa

Comment: No, this is what I'm using already (as per the Transactional annotation). I am just wondering if I could avoid the need to pass a list. The only solution I found so far is to store records in a buffer and then when the batch is complete call a transactional method that takes data from the buffer and commits the updates/inserts.

Answer (score 0):

What prevents you from extracting those 3 methods and call them from within insertBatchIntoT1?